# How do I turn the value the other way?

Tags: javascript

I have a event scroll.

it has a value

```
item.scrollTop = 320.
```

When I start to scroll up the value changes.
319, 318, 319 etc...

How can I get the second value only that goes the other way?
For example, var return = 320

```
item.scrollTop = 320, return = 320
item.scrollTop = 321, return = 319
item.scrollTop = 322, return = 318
item.scrollTop = 323, return = 317
```

Now I'm doing it like this.

```
var return = Math.abs(item.scrollTop - 320) + 320;
```

On the screenshot, I scrolled down. And then I went back upstairs. And the value didn't go back 320 to 320.
[image]

But it's not always true and I don't understand why. tnx

Comment: Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```js
function offset(n) {
  return (320 - n) + 320
}

offset(320) //=> 320
offset(322) //=> 318
offset(318) //=> 322
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example and the results I think you want, try this out instead.

```
(item.scrollTop - 320) * -1 + 320
```

`Math.abs` will always return a positive value, but I think what you want is simple subtract 320, flip the remainder, then add 320 again.